# ASP.NET Conversion from string to date issue after updating to Windows 8.1

Tags: asp.net, date, iis-7

On my development laptop, I decided to update from Windows 8 to Windows 8.1 (finally) and prior to this the conversion to date worked.

I'm in Australia so it's dd/mm/yyyy, and I know the issue would be the format is now being interrogated as mm/dd/yyyy hence the error.

So basically Windows 8 (just hours ago, my application works fine), Windows 8.1 updated and it completely messed it up.

- I've checked the Globalisation configuration in IIS -> Set to Australia and back to Invariant Language (since our deployed servers are all invariant)
- I've checked the regional settings -> Location Australia, date format dd/mm/yyyy

What else can I do? Something went wrong on my development laptop and i mainly required it so I can run IE11 for testing purposes and now all my applications have gone to grave T_T

Thanks in advance for any advice or help.

Comment: Can you put a break point in your code and check what the current culture is set to? (`Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`)

Comment: @AnthonyChu It's @ en-US which I figured as much, I just don't know where it's overwriting. I'm doing all kinds of crazy things now like installing Australian language package too T_T

Comment: [Since I can't answer my own question and I probably won't come back after 8 hours] I don't know how I resolved this but I finally fixed it but the key lies in the Region settings

Started removing US region from languages and installing Australian English Pack
Changed Input Language (after that)
Removed all of it and started fresh again.
The last thing I did was copy current settings to welcome screen, system accounts and new user accounts.

So playing around with the region settings worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options. The simplest is probably adding a `<globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-AU" />` section to your web.config if you want this setting to be application-wide. See other options here...

[How to: Set the Culture and UI Culture for ASP.NET Web Page Globalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx)

The `culture` drives how .NET formats dates, currencies, etc. `uiCulture` determines which resource files to use.

Comment: Pretty much what I'm left with doing even though it's not ideal. I did do this ages ago but figured there was someone out there that can figure out why my whole computer (registry too) is en-AU and only on ASP.NET is it on en-US and it doesn't even inherit from the root. #RegretUpgradeToWindows8.1